# Puzzling Cross Browser Display Issue With Product Columns in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, mozilla, multiple-columns

I have a site on Big Commerce that has some real puzzling display issues. When looking at the homepage in chrome http://omgdecor.com/ Under the "New Products" section their are 4 columns of products. If you look at this same page and section in Firefox it displays only 3 columns. I need it to always be 4 columns. I don't see the problem, anyone with some direction or answers?

Answer (score 0):

Your source indicates that those li elements have an inline style setting the width. Chrome reports this:

```
<li class="Odd" style="width: 159px !important; height 316px;">...</li>
```

But Firefox reports this:

```
<li style="width: 251px; height: 301px;" class="Odd">...</li>
```

Whatever is generating those list item elements is your problem.